# What's the second character?

Tags: kanji, handwriting

[image]

Can someone tell me what the second character is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's 難 "difficulty". The text reads [厄難消除]{やくなんしょうじょ}, and is a wish for the removal of misfortunes and difficulties.

Answer (score 4):

This is 難. The whole phrase is 厄難消除【やくなんしょうじょ】. The style of writing used here is called 行書【ぎょうしょ】 which is sometimes called "semi-cursive" script in English. The full cursive script is called 草書【そうしょ】.

See [Google images](https://www.google.com/search?q=%E8%A1%8C%E6%9B%B8+%E9%9B%A3&tbm=isch) for more examples.